# how to configure convertrecord processor in Apache nifi so that it convert JSON to AVRO format

Tags: apache-nifi, dataflow

not able to figure out how to configure this processor to convert the incoming JSON twitter data to Avro to Put that data into a hive table

plz help

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RishiPandey

[ConvertJsonToAvro](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kite-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kite.ConvertJSONToAvro/) is the processor you need.

Comment: this processor is not available now in the current version of NiFi

Comment: Sure it is. All processors are capable in NiFi.  What you have is likely a bundled release where cloudera controlled the file size and took out stuff they didnt want in the release.    You can add custom processors yourself, from any previous version.

Comment: can you tell me how I can contact you regarding a problem in the dataflow I have created in nifi Really need help...

Comment: You can reach me directly at: steven@dfheinz.com